# What plant kind of shrub is this?

Tags: shrubs

[image]

Anyone know what plant this is? It’s some kind of bush / shrub or hedge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be one  of the Coprosma varieties -  might be Coprosma 'fireburst' or maybe Coprosma 'inferno', image and some info on other varieties here https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/plants-blogs/plants/may-2014/coprosma-inferno-new-from-hillier